# How to create an IBM Cloud VSI using a custom image

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud

I want to use Terraform to create a new virtual server using an existing Customer Image, just like manually under https://cloud.ibm.com/vpc-ext/compute/images.
I used an example code snippet and only replaced the name of the image (r010-...).

```
data "ibm_is_image" "centos" {
   name = "r010-489ff05b-1494-4a05-8b12-c6f44a958859"
}

# Virtual Server Insance
resource "ibm_is_instance" "vsi1" {
   name    = "${local.BASENAME}-vsi1"
   vpc     = ibm_is_vpc.vpc-instance.id
   keys    = [data.ibm_is_ssh_key.ssh_key_id.id]
   zone    = local.ZONE
   image   = data.ibm_is_image.centos.id
   profile = "cx2-2x4"
   
   # References to the subnet and security groups
   primary_network_interface {
     subnet          = ibm_is_subnet.subnet1.id
     security_groups = [ibm_is_security_group.sg1.id]
   }
}
```

The error message is:

```
Error: No image found with name  r010-489ff05b-1494-4a05-8b12-c6f44a958859
```

It seems that only public AWS images can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're using `id` in place of `name` here

```
data "ibm_is_image" "centos" {
   name = "r010-489ff05b-1494-4a05-8b12-c6f44a958859"
}
```

try using the `name` of the image

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example: https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/isv-vsi-product-deploy-sample/blob/main/image-map.tf

This terraform file has image ids for different regions. Based on your VSI region, it will fetch the image id.

Answer (score 0):

Your [custom images are private](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/vpc?topic=vpc-managing-images#import-custom-image). The **visibility** is an attribute that you can specify when [looking up the data using **ibm_is_image**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/data-sources/is_image).

Thus, I recommend trying:

```
data "ibm_is_image" "centos" {
   name       = "r010-489ff05b-1494-4a05-8b12-c6f44a958859"
   visibility = "private"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Same error message. According to https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/is_instance only public images are supported "To list supported images, run ibmcloud is images."

Answer (score 0):

I confused name with id. The image name is expected rather than the id. Thanks!